# Woocommerce and WPML: Creating and traducing products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

When I create a product with the methods of "WC_Product" with WPML enabled by default Woo creates it in the English language.

How can I determine the product creation language?

```
$product = new WC_Product;

$product->set_name('My test product');
$product->set_slug('test-product');
$product->set_description('This is my test product');
$product->set_sku('some_sku');

$product->save();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should better ask that in WPML support.

Answer (score 0):

I done it with the methods from $sitepress object:

```
global $sitepress;

// Create the product in defaul language
// First switch de language for the product to create
$language_code_default = 'es';
$sitepress->switch_lang($language_code_default);

// Create product with de Woo methods
$product_es = new WC_Product;
$product_es->set_name('PRODUCTO EN ESPAÑOL');
$product_es->set_slug('producto-wc');
$product_es->set_description('Este producto ha sido creado con WC_Product');
$product_es->set_short_description('Este producto ha sido creado con WC_Product');
$post_id_es = $product_es->save();

// Create the traduction
// Remember, switch the traduction language
$language_code_tr = 'en';
$sitepress->switch_lang($language_code_tr);
$product_en = new WC_Product;
$product_en->set_name('PRODUCT IN ENGLISH');
$product_en->set_slug('producto-wc-en');
$product_en->set_description('This product was made from spanish version');
$product_en->set_short_description('This product was made from spanish version');
$post_id_en = $product_en->save();

// And use the wpml methods to link de traduction with the original language
$element_type = 'post_product';
$trid = $sitepress->get_element_trid($post_id_es, $element_type);
$sitepress->set_element_language_details($post_id_en, $element_type, $trid, $language_code_tr, $language_code_default);

// And then copy de product meta from de original to the traduction
$sitepress->copy_custom_fields($post_id_es, $post_id_en);
```